# Getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" when subscribing to Observable in Angular + .NET Core MVC application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, asp.net-core-mvc

I installed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates as described in this [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/) and used `dotnet new angular` to create a new project. Got the base site up and running just fine; I am using Visual Studio 2017.

I added a service with a simple http get. The data comes back fine and I return it to the caller as an Observable; from there I subscribe to the Observable and do something with the data. That's where the issue comes up.. if I subscribe to the Observable, it complains:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

The weird thing is if I run the site first without the subscribe so that it runs, and *then* add the subscribe, [HMR](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html) does it's thing, updates the browser and everything works great. But every time I refresh the browser manually after that, or try to re-run the site, it throws the error.

The code:

---

**home.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private homeService: HomeService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.homeService.getData(5)
            .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
    }
}
```

**home.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
    private _apiUrl = 'http://localhost:1234/api';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getData(count: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .get(`${this._apiUrl}/Foo/${count}`, { withCredentials: true })
            .map(response => response.json())
    }
}
```

---

I know the data from the web api is valid JSON. The part that fails is when I try to subscribe to the Observable, and I have no idea why it's complaining. If I do something like the following:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('observable', this.homeService.getData(5));
}
```

.. then it prints out the Observable object to the console just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your api is probably not returning jason data this error thrown by calling `response.json()` it is failing to convert your response body to json try to console response.body in your observable map

Comment: When I am accessing my data locally, my apiUrl does *not* include the localhost info. Mine looks like this for example: `private baseUrl = 'api/products';` What happens if you just change the url to `api`?

Comment: @BabarBilal If i use response.body I get an error "Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Response'". I know the api is returning valid JSON when I test it in Postman.. it looks like [{ "var1": 123, ... }]

Comment: @DeborahK I have a separate WebAPI project that I've deployed to a local IIS website.. it is not part of the same angular project. I'm hardcoding the full url in my component for testing purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at @DeborahK's Angular-Routing repo for observable examples and realized I wasn't handling errors on the caller.

I changed the code in the component like this:

```
this.homeService.getData(5)
    .subscribe(
        (res) => console.log(res),
        (err) => console.log(err)
    );
```

and no longer receive the error. Thanks!